# Как отфильтровать объекты в Django queryset и подсчитать агрегированные данные по каждому объекту?

Tags: python, django

Мне нужно оставить новейшее появление cell_name в журнале Kpi. При этом требуется посчитать количество записей с этим cell_name в журнале. Я реализовал это следующим образом:

```
class Kpi2GList(ListView):
    template_name = 'stat_journal/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        new_events = Kpi2G.objects.exclude(comment__isnull=False).order_by('-date_insert', 'cell_name')
        cells = dict()
        for event in new_events:
            if event.cell_name not in cells.keys():
                cells[event.cell_name] = [event, 1]
            else:
                cells[event.cell_name][1] += 1
        return  cells
```

Проблема в том, что в результате на выходе имеем словарь вместо queryset. В результате ломается пагинация. Как можно отфильтровать эти значения, подсчитать cellname и вернуть в виде query set? БД Oracle

Comment: А если передать в шаблон не QuerySet, а список объектов, то пагинация не ломается? Если все нормально, то на основе этого можно придумать решение. Проверьте `return list(new_events)`

Comment: Разобрался, у меня сам шаблон был недопилен.